Driver using a scripted property isn't working
I have this script that works the way I think it should, it reads the input of an Xbox controller's A button, then changes it to 1 or 0 if it's pressed. You can then see the number updated in a menu in the tool panel on the 3d viewport.
The problem is that when I try to use this property in a driver it always reads 0 and never changes even though the panel I copied the path from shows the property changing values when I press the A button. I don't understand if this is an issue with my script or with the way I'm trying to make a driver
import bpy
import XInput

# Define a custom panel
class SimpleNumberPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Controller Inputs"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_simple_number_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tool'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        layout.prop(scene, "simple_number")

# Function to update the number property
def update_number():
    print(bpy.context.scene.simple_number)

    controllerState = XInput.get_state(0) 
    if XInput.get_button_values(controllerState)['A']: 
        bpy.context.scene.simple_number  = 1 
    else: 
        bpy.context.scene.simple_number = 0 

    # Redraw all areas to update the panel
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            area.tag_redraw()

# Register the panel and property
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleNumberPanel)

    bpy.types.Scene.simple_number = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="A Button",
        description="A simple number",
        default=0
    )
    
    # Start the timer to update the number
    bpy.app.timers.register(update_number, first_interval= 0.1)

# Unregister the panel and property
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleNumberPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.simple_number
    # Unregister the timer (by not re-registering it)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```


That seems rather an odd thing to do but I feel like it should work. I remember a motion capture plugin that must’ve worked in a similar fashion.

Erindale has created a node group to work with a Gameboy controller as part of a series on Geometry nodes. Apparently it only works with Windows PCs but the tutorial to get and use it is here.

Chat GPT generated script?

Okay so I will check out Erindales addon, I really freaking youtube showed that to me the first 100 times I searched for "use a controller in blender". Looking at just the description of the addon it looks like he too may have encountered this and worked around it by just manipulating the transforms and then making drivers off of those.
